# Bitbucket SSH Key loading but not working

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to set up two different SSH keys for my bitbucket account, work, and personal. As usual I add my public key to my SSH keys on the server, but for some unusual reason when I open my public key to add it, I see it starts with

`---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` and `---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`.

Bitbucket doesn't like these so instead I copy it from the field at the top of PuttyGen, which doesn't have these fields and then Bitbucket accepts it.

HOWEVER,

When I then load my privaye key into Pageant it works fine, but I then try any operations with my server (clone, push, pull, even viewing remote on existing repos) It says my key isn't authenticated!!

I've also tried the `ssh-keygen` command from git bash, but these come out the same format and again, BitBucket doesn't like them.

Thanks.

Comment: "ssh-keygen command from git bash, but these come out the same format and again": it should not. It should generate a id_rsa.pub public key, that you can copy to Bitbucket.

Comment: Sorry @VonC by that I meant it comes out with the `---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----` and `---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`

Comment: Do yo have an id_rsa.pub?

Comment: @VonC I do but it doesn't work, Pageant doesn't recognize it

Comment: You don't need pageant. "Bitbucket doesn't like these": it should like any public key from an id_rsa.pub

Comment: @VonC See here for my error from Pageant. I tried not loading it in and it didn't work. (apologies for uploading the image I can't add an attachment) [www.9Bytes.com/temp/SSH.PNG](http://www.testing.9Bytes.co.uk/temp/SSH.PNG)

Comment: Why load it in Pageant? Do you have a passphrase-protected private key?

Comment: @VonC No, but my system is configured to use Pageant, and it doesn't load it any other way.

Comment: OK. I don't use pageant. Openssh is usually enough.

Comment: @VonC Ok thanks, however, I've just tried the `ssh-add` command in cygwin and I got [this](http://www.testing.9Bytes.co.uk/temp/Cygwin.PNG)

Comment: Cygwin??? What would you use cygwin with git? The git for windows works just fine.https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: I know and I also have that but I was just trying it because I got the same error in Git Bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't an issue to do with either SSH or Bitbucket, I didn't realise but over the weekend my workplace proxy had been updated, and it didn't like BitBucket connections. For future reference, the proxy client was 'Cisco AnyConnect', and ALL the proxy locations caused issues.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. +1. I would still advise against Cygwin or pageant ;)